# Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in C:\AppServ\www\siin\core\app\model\SellData2.php on line 10

Tags: php

```
<?php
class SellData2 {
    public static $tablename = "sell";


    public function SellData2(){
        $this->estado = "";
        $this->discount = "";
    }

    public function add_sell(){
        $sql = "insert into sell (estado,discount) ";
        $sql .= "value (\"$this->estado\",\"$this->discount)";
        Executor::doit($sql);
    }


    public static function delById($id){
        $sql = "delete from ".self::$tablename." where id=$id";
        Executor::doit($sql);
    }
    public function del(){
        $sql = "delete from ".self::$tablename." where id=$this->id";
        Executor::doit($sql);
    }

// partiendo de que ya tenemos creado un objecto SellData2 previamente utilizamos el contexto
    public function update(){
        $sql = "update ".self::$tablename." set estado=\"$this->estado\",discount=\"$this->discount";
        Executor::doit($sql);
    }

    public function update_sell(){
        $sql = "update ".self::$tablename." set estado=\"$this->estado\",discount=\"$this->discount";
        Executor::doit($sql);
    }



    public static function getById($id){
        $sql = "select * from ".self::$tablename." where id=$id";
        $query = Executor::doit($sql);
        $found = null;
        $data = new SellData2();
        while($r = $query[0]->fetch_array()){
            $data->id = $r['id'];
            $data->estado = $r['estado'];
            $data->discount = $r['discount'];
            $found = $data;
            break;
        }
        return $found;
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: debes declarar los attributos ejemplo: `public static $tablename = "sell";private $estado; private $discount;`

Answer (score 0):

Tienes muchos errores en ese código, para empezar, tu constructor es obsoleto; tener una función con el mismo nombre de la clase se hizo obsoleto a partir de PHP 5.

```
class SellData2 {
    public function SellData2() { // <-- Constructor PHP v4
    }
}
```

La forma correcta a partir de la versión 5 de PHP es esta:

```
class SellData2 {
    public function __construct() { // <-- Constructor PHP v5 en adelante
    }
}
```

Otro error es mezclar propiedades y métodos estáticos con no-estáticos:

- Estáticos: No requieren que se cree una instancia de la clase y necesitas agregar el prefijo `self::` o `nombreDeClase::` para acceder a ellos
- No-estáticos: Se debe crear una instancia de la clase y necesitas agregar el prefijo `$this->` o `$nombreDeObjeto->` para acceder a ellos

### ¿Puedes combinarlos?

Sí, por supuesto, puedes tener propiedades y métodos tanto estáticos como no-estáticos, pero debes tener una razón específica para cada uno de ellos y siempre deberás acceder en la forma en que los definiste, por ejemplo:

```
class SellData2 {
    public static $tablename;
    public $estado;

    public function __construct($tablename, $estado) {
        self::$tablename = $tablename;
        $this->estado = $estado;
    }
}
```

La propiedad `$tablename` es estática y siempre deberás acceder a ella con `self::` o `SellData2::`, mientras que `$estado` es no-estático y siempre accedes con `$this->` o `$nombreDeObjeto->`.

#### Ejemplo de uso de propiedades estáticas

```
// Puedes cambiar el valor sin instanciar la clase
SellData2::$tablename = 'productos';
// También puedes obtenerlo sin problema
$nombreTabla = SellData2::$tablename;
```

Parece bueno, ¿cierto? El problema es que ese valor puede ser modificado fácilmente y, si no tienes buen control sobre lo que estás haciendo, los resultados pueden ser impredecibles, donde quiera que cambies el valor, será el mismo para todas las clases y funciones que accedan a ella.

#### Ejemplo de uso de propiedades no-estáticas

```
// Debes instanciar la clase, proporcionando parámetros (a menos que sean opcionales)
$pantalla = new SellData2('productos', 'Vendido');
// Cambiar el valor de una propiedad
$pantalla->estado = 'Disponible';

// Crear otra instancia de la clase
$teclado = new SellData2('productos', 'Disponible');
// Cambiar valor de la propiedad
$teclado->estado = 'Otro valor';

// Cada objeto tendrá la propiedad con su propio valor
echo $pantalla->estado; // Disponible
echo $teclado->estado; // Otro valor

// No puedes acceder a las propiedades estáticas desde el objeto
$pantalla->tablename = 'electronicos'; // Genera error
// Tampoco puedes acceder a las propiedades no-estáticas sin instanciar la clase
SellData::$estado = 'Vendido'; // También genera error
```

**Nota:** Esto es un resumen (un tanto burdo) de cómo se usan propiedades y métodos en las clases, pero vas a tener que investigar mucho para entenderlo completamente y decidir cómo lo vas a aplicar en tus proyectos.

Para terminar, te comento el último error: En este método estás combinando el uso de propiedades y métodos estáticos con no-estáticos y, además, las propiedades no están definidas previamente, que no es un error como tal, pero sí una mala práctica.

```
public function update_sell(){
    $sql = "update ".self::$tablename." set estado=\"$this->estado\",discount=\"$this->discount";
    Executor::doit($sql);
}

public static function getById($id){
    $sql = "select * from ".self::$tablename." where id=$id";
    $query = Executor::doit($sql);
    $found = null;
    $data = new SellData2();
    while($r = $query[0]->fetch_array()){
        $data->id = $r['id'];
        $data->estado = $r['estado'];
        $data->discount = $r['discount'];
        $found = $data;
        break;
    }
    return $found;
}
```

Comment: Muy claro gracias a todos.